# Copy value from 1 column to another

Tags: linux, shell

Here is a csv file in the linux system. This is one line from the file.

```
:/var/opt/data# vi data_2018_07.csv

LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,1056.gz
```

Similarly, we have 10,000 line in that file. All we want to do is to add an incremental value (24th value) at a place between `NO,xxxx.gz` such as:-

```
LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,1, 1056.gz
LGRDR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,2, 1057.gz
```

Can we do that throughout the file for all rows using a small shell script? 
Note: Rows are different in each row.

Comment: Utilities like awk, cut and paste come to mind, but all of these have the disadvantage that they'll run into problems if there is a comma between quotes, e.g., the first entry of a row would be `"LG,PAR"` instead of `LGPAR`. In addition, bash and friends have substring replacement, but that generally requires you to know the exact location (in number of characters) of a string to be replaced.

Comment: I'd advice picking a programming language you're comfortable with and that has a decent CSV library, and write a short program to do what you want. There may also be a set of tools that can already do what you want, but you these may not come standard with your system. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$24 = NR FS $24} 1' file.csv
```

```
LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,1,1056.gz
```

To save changes in the same file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$24 = NR FS $24} 1' file.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv file.csv
```

Comment: thanks. It works. But I have comma after the value last in the row as well - ,1056.gz,

Comment: In that case try: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$(NF-1) = $3 OFS $(NF-1)} 1' file.csv`

Comment: a change in request - to replace 24th value (the one we replaced from 3rd column value)  of each line (separated by comma) should be incremental values. Can we replace 24th value/column with 1 for row1, 2, for row2, ...?

Comment: Done. Pls check.

Comment: Upvote. I guess you're the one who can answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245500/how-can-i-handle-multiple-htaccess-files-on-nginx), since I get similar answer from you already.Please take a look at it if you have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *awk*:

```
awk -F"," '{ printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $3, $24, $25); }'  yourcsv-file
```

gives:

LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,61543261,1056.gz

Comment: these are 25 values separated by comma and we need to copy value from column 3 (61543261) to column 24 (between NO,1056.gz).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my awk-oneliner which at least works with the data you provided

```
awk '{ split($0, fields, ","); split($0, parts, "NO,NO,NO,"); printf "%s%s%s,%s\n", parts[1], "NO,NO,NO,", fields[3], parts[2] }'
```

1. split the record into pieces using comma as a separator to extract the third field
2. split the record again, this time using "NO,NO,NO," as a separator
3. printf puts it back toghether: part before NO,NO,NO, then NO,NO,NO, then the copy of third field and the remainder of the record

As said before, it might throw problems if there is a quoted comma in the first two fields...